# Checked Selector-like for amp-accordion?

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

I was wondering if there was a way to style, display/hide an element outside of an accordion based on that said accordion's state ie collapsed or expanded.

I see you can style content inside the accordion itself based on state but haven't found ability to say: if this accordion-blank is expanded, hide this image over here etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by listening to the `expand` and `collapse` event:

```
<amp-accordion>
    <section on="expand:myElement.show;
                 collapse:myElement.hide">
    ...
```

When any of these events is fired you can trigger any of [AMP's built-in actions](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events/#*-(all-elements)), such as `toggle` (show/hide) or `toggleClass`.

Here is a full example:

```
  <amp-accordion>
    <section on="expand:myElement.show;
                 collapse:myElement.hide">
      <h2>
        Toggle Visibility
      </h2>
      <div>
        Content 1
      </div>
    </section>
    <section on="expand:myOtherElement.toggleClass(class='red');
                 collapse:myOtherElement.toggleClass(class='red')">
      <h2>
        Toggle Class
      </h2>
      <div>
        Content 2
      </div>
    </section>
  </amp-accordion>

  <div id="myElement" hidden>
    Element 1
  </div>
  <div id="myOtherElement">
    Element 2
  </div>
```